# Working with global document object in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

We are using nextjs and trying to change the styling on a button click with `document.getElementById` but the styling does n't change irrespective of whatever we do.

pages/index.js

```
function Index() {
  
   function change(){
     console.log('changing');
     document.getElementById('navi').style.color='blue';
   }
   return (<Some test={change}> </Some>)

}
```

Now, there is another normal react-component outside pages directory and is as below.

```
function Some(prop){
 return (<div id="navi">
          <button onClick={prop.test}></button>
       </div>);
}
```

Now, whenever we click on the button it is executing the `change()` function in index.js and prints the console.log as 'changing' but the `document.getElementById` never works.
Is there any specific reason for this, Please let us know.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use of useRef instead of id and then on the onClick when you call prop.test you have to pass that ref as an argument like this:

```
function change(e){
  e.current.style.color="blue"
}

const navi= useRef(null)
<div ref={navi}>
          <button onClick={()=>prop.test(navi)}></button>
       </div>
```

Comment: Thanks but the way of using id is still expected to work and is not restricted to useRef usage.